# ParseException: Expected end of text

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying to parse text using pyparsing. My function is shown below. Firstly, I construct a list containing all the terms in my dictionary (a dictionary of commonly used terms in my website). Then I set my grammar to be this list of commonly used words. Then I construct the ZeroOrMore object with the grammar. Finally, I parse the string and I should get the matches found in my string. However, it throws a ParseException instead complaining that end of text was expected.

```
def map_dict_words(self, pbody):
        dict_terms = [term.term for term in Dictionary.objects()]
        look_for_these = oneOf(dict_terms, caseless=True).setResultsName("dict_words")
        parseobj = ZeroOrMore(look_for_these)
        matches = parseobj.parseString(pbody, parseAll=True)
        print matches
```

According to the FAQ in pyparsing's homepage http://pyparsing-public.wikispaces.com/FAQs if I want the parser to parse the entire string I should either put StringEnd() in my grammar or use the optional arg parseAll=True. If I remove parseAll=True from my code it works but it doesn't parse the entire string.

Any ideas?

Comment: >> "However, it throws a ParseException instead complaining that end of text was expected." - As you can see in pyparsing FAQ - it raises exaclty ParseException complaining that the end of text was expected. That is how it works - it's his behaviour. Don't think it's possible to make pyparsing parse all of text after INVALID syntax is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of pyparsing as a more advanced regular expression. When you pass it `parseAll=True`, it expects to match the entire string, qualifying each and every byte to some part of the grammar. Your grammar however only mentions some of the words that will appear in the string. You have to account for the rest of them somehow.

In other words, assuming that popular words are "parrot", "hovercraft", "eels" and "fjords", you have built an equivalent of the following regular expression:

```
/^(?P<dict_words>eels|fjords|hovercraft|parrot)*$/
```

Comment: Hey thanks. So basically I must construct another grammar which will match the rest of the string and I can distinguihs between the two matched set by setting the results name, right?

Comment: Yes, you can also tell pyparsing to ignore parts of text that match certain criteria so you only end up with valuable results in the parsed output.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `parseString`, you may be more interested in using `scanString` or `searchString`. Unlike `parseString`, these functions skim through the input looking for matches, instead of requiring a complete match of all the content in the input string.  `scanString` returns a generator, so for large input text, will give you matches as they are found:

```
for toks,start,end in look_for_these.scanString(pbody):
    print toks[0], start, end
```

`searchString` is just a simple wrapper around `scanString` (drops start and end locations, though):

```
for t in look_for_these.searchString(pbody):
    print t[0]
```